# Can I add a new plumbing vent rather than extending to an existing one?

Tags: plumbing

Can I run a separate 2 inch vent pipe from the kitchen sink through the roof? Moving sink 8 feet away from original spot to under a window. I cant drill all those studs to extend vent pipe, so I was hoping to just shoot a 2 inch pipe up beside the window through the roof just for kitchen sink.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - if it's relatively easy to run an additional vent pipe, then yes, it is permissible.

See: https://www.bhg.com/home-improvement/plumbing/drain-venting/